# Smarter way of doing array initialization?

Tags: c, arrays

I need to initialize a fixes size arrays quite often, like so:

```
for( uint16_t q=0; q<SIZE; q++ ) 
    array[q]=value;
```

Array is defined as `float array[SIZE];`

Is there a nicer way of doing this, replacing with a macro or similar?

p.s. 
Not allowed to use `mem___` calls.

Comment: What nicer than this and without `memset` or `memcpy`? What type is `array`?

Comment: Is this `value` known at compile time or you get it run time?

Comment: Please define "nicer".

Comment: This code isn't doing initialization, it is doing assignment. What are you looking for, initialization or assignment?

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate, I didn't find anwer there. Please reopen.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" is totaly different question. People, I am not asking how to "initialize all members of an array to the same value", but how to write a nice code that does the same thing.

Comment: @Danijel Again as Michael Walz said, define "Nice code"... It varies from person to person... For me, what you have is nice...

Comment: This looks nice: `INITIALIZE(myarr, SIZE, 0.0f);`.

Comment: But in the question you ask how to do "array initialization", not about "code that does the same thing". If you find that nice, define a macro to do it for you

Comment: I give up......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With preprocessor you can do like this:

```
#define NMEMBERS(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*(x)))
#define ARRSET(arr, val) \
    do { \
        size_t i; \
        for (i = 0; i < NMEMBERS(arr); ++i) \
            (arr)[i] = val; \
    } while (0)

float array[SIZE], val = 0.67f;
ARRSET(array, val);
```

Comment: Why would you write such an ugly macro for such a simple thing? Just write a plain for loop, end of story. There's no need to obfuscate the code to oblivion.

Comment: Imagine dozen of those loops. This looks nicer: `INITIALIZE(myarr, SIZE, 0.0f);` don't you think.

Comment: @Danijel No it looks really bad. C programmers understand C code, they don't understand "my private, secret macro language". There exist no way in C that lets you write this more elegantly than `for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++) { arr[i] = val; }`. Assuming we're talking about run-time assignment here, it isn't clear.

Comment: What's ugly? You can make convention about naming of macro-functions so that you would recognize them in the code. What are the problems? The task is simple, I need an array initialization function, the amount of which is known by the compiler. I don't want write simple loop every time when I need that.

Comment: @Danijel You can have two variants: `ARRNSET(arr, size, 0,0f)` and `ARRSET(arr, 0.0f)`

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have built-in way to initialize the entire array to some non-zero value.

If you use GCC, it has [Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) extension. You can use it like:

```
float widths[] = { [0 ... 99] = 3.14 };
```

This set all of the elements to `3.14`.